# Driver for AMD M880G with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, vga, gateway

I have [Gateway NV53](http://support.gateway.com/product/?cmpid=topnav) nootebook and I just reinstalled my windows 7  .

Before the reinstal I had display adapter - **AMD M880G with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200** like this   -

[image]

After I reinstalled the windows 7 I installed the VGA package from the above link of Gateway site and I now just see the **Standard VGA Graphics Adapter** under display adapter  -

[image]

How could I install this VGA ?

**Edit:**

Finally I downloaded [AMD Driver Autodetect](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/auto_detect.aspx) and it detected graphics hardware - **Mobility Radeon HD 4xxx Series**  ,  I downloaded to appropriate driver and it worked out  .

Comment: Post your Edit as an answer instead and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is available at the [Gateway NV53](http://support.gateway.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=2374) support site.

Simply download and install the ATI driver.

Windows simply did not have a driver and used a generic VGA one.

Comment: That's what I installed before and still I have **Standart VGA Graphics Adapter**

Comment: righ click on the VGA adapter, select properties -> driver and update the driver. Now point to the path where the setup extracts the tempoary files (C:\AMD)